# How to access virtual memory of some process from driver on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, driver

I have a kernel-mode driver on Windows XP and I need to access virtual memory of some process, which PID I know. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your current process is requested process, it is already done. You already have access.
2. If you are in other process use PsLookupProcessByProcessId to find the PEPROCESS and KeStackAttachProcess to attach to the requested process address space.